Utilizar el dashboard AdminLTD en AWS Cloud9
He realizado un projecto con Laravel en Cloud9, y despues he implementado la plantilla de AdminLTD para implementar el formulario.
Mi problema es que no funcionan los estilos css de la plantilla.
Esto es lo que se ve:

y esto es lo que se deberia de ver:


Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.
